# disable order by in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select HId, TestM, *
from TestDb
where Hid in ( 4, 5, 7, 9, 1, 132, 312)
```

If I run the above .sql file the first column will be sorted ascending by default.

I do want the Hid column to be in order of the values inside the where clause. How can I achieve this?

```
Hid | TestM | ...
_______________
4

5

7

9

1

132

312
```

Comment: you have to create some column to order by. there is no "default" sorting as SQL is not guaranteed to return the results in a consistent ordering without an order by clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT HId, TestM, *
FROM TestDb
WHEN Hid IN ( 4, 5, 7, 9, 1, 132, 312)
ORDER BY CASE Hid 
            WHEN 4 THEN 1
            WHEN 5 THEN 2
            WHEN 7 THEN 3
            WHEN 9 THEN 4
            WHEN 1 THEN 5
            WHEN 132 THEN 6
            WHEN 312 THEN 7
         END
```

Also note that tables are just unordered sets, so if you leave the `ORDER BY` clause out, then there is no guaranteed order for your result set.

Comment: In my where clause I have >3k values inside the ( ... )

Comment: @FlorinM. In that case I'm afraid there is no easy alternative to the above. You have to somehow specify order for each separate value of the `IN` clause. You can store this info to a table and then `JOIN`, but the info has to be somewhere, so that you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

SQL doesn't have implicit ordering.  If no `ORDER BY` is stated then the results can come back in any order, and potentially different orders each time the same query is executed on the same data.

The often used approach is to use a CASE statement, but that can become clunky...

```
ORDER BY
    CASE HId WHEN   4 THEN 1
             WHEN   5 THEN 2
             WHEN   7 THEN 3
             WHEN   8 THEN 4
             WHEN   1 THEN 5
             WHEN 123 THEN 6
             WHEN 312 THEN 7 END
```

An alternative is to JOIN on a table that includes both the values you are filtering by, and a column to sort.  It's slightly less clunky, more relational and a bit easier to expand...

```
SELECT
    TestDB.HId, TestDB.TestM, TestDB.*
FROM
    TestDB
INNER JOIN
(
              SELECT   4 AS val, 1 AS ordinal
    UNION ALL SELECT   5 AS val, 2 AS ordinal
    UNION ALL SELECT   7 AS val, 3 AS ordinal
    UNION ALL SELECT   8 AS val, 4 AS ordinal
    UNION ALL SELECT   1 AS val, 5 AS ordinal
    UNION ALL SELECT 132 AS val, 6 AS ordinal
    UNION ALL SELECT 312 AS val, 7 AS ordinal
)
    filter
        ON filter.value = TestDB.HId
ORDER BY
    filter.ordinal
```